# What's a clean way to check for an objects type?

Tags: gwt

I want to make a distinction in my code based on the type of an object.
What is a clean (and performant) way to accomplish that?

My object will either be an instance of class A,B or C. All of them extend a class S.

```
if (obj instanceof A) {...}
```

Would be what I do in plain java. Is this also good in GWT (or JavaScript at the end)?

Answer (score 0):

Basically the answer is yes if you have declarations like this,

```
S objA = new A();
S objB = new B();
S objC = new C();

if(objA instacneofc A) //true
if(objB instacneofc A) //false
if(objC instacneofc C) //true
```

Comment: @gue you can safely answer your own question and mark it accepted or just do it here so that the question will get closed..